# Modeling embedded hardware in Rust and how to have multiple mutable references cleanly?

Tags: rust, emulation

I'm modeling a system that has a CPU, GPU, MMU, APU, and maybe other things. The CPU will have mutable references to the GPU, MMU, and APU. I also would like the MMU to have a way to be able to call specific functions on the GPU and APU. Where this comes into play is when I'm mapping memory to different locations. The MMU takes care of that, and will dispatch to GPU or APU if the memory request is in those devices.

Here is how I modeled it using `Arc` and `Mutex`. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of achieving what I did here, or if this is the correct method.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait MMU {
    fn read(&self, addr: usize) -> u8;
    fn write(&mut self, addr: usize, value: u8);
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Cpu {
    apu: Arc<Mutex<Box<MMU>>>,
    mmu: Box<Mmu>,
    gpu: Arc<Mutex<Box<MMU>>>,
}

struct Mmu {
    map: Vec<(usize, usize, Arc<Mutex<Box<MMU>>>)>,
}

impl Mmu {
    fn new() -> Mmu {
        Mmu { map: vec![] }
    }

    fn add_mapping(&mut self, start: usize, end: usize, cb: Arc<Mutex<Box<MMU>>>) {
        self.map.push((start, end, cb));
    }

    fn read(&self, addr: usize) -> u8 {
        // See if the addr is in a range that is mapped, then
        // call read on it.
        for i in self.map.iter() {
            if i.0 <= addr && addr <= i.1 {
                let d = i.2.clone();
                let d = d.lock().unwrap();
                return d.read(addr);
            }
        }

        println!("Mmu.read: {}", addr);
        0
    }

    fn write(&mut self, addr: usize, value: u8) {
        // See if the addr is in a range that is mapped, then
        // call write on it.
        for i in self.map.iter() {
            if i.0 <= addr && addr <= i.1 {
                let d = i.2.clone();
                let mut d = d.lock().unwrap();
                d.write(addr, value);
                return;
            }
        }

        println!("Mmu.write: {} {}", addr, value);
    }
}

struct Gpu;
impl MMU for Gpu {
    fn read(&self, addr: usize) -> u8 {
        println!("Gpu.read: {}", addr);
        0
    }

    fn write(&mut self, addr: usize, value: u8) {
        println!("Gpu.write: {} {}", addr, value);
    }
}

struct Apu;
impl MMU for Apu {
    fn read(&self, addr: usize) -> u8 {
        println!("Apu.read: {}", addr);
        0
    }

    fn write(&mut self, addr: usize, value: u8) {
        println!("Apu.write: {} {}", addr, value);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let apu = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(Apu) as Box<MMU>));
    let gpu = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(Gpu) as Box<MMU>));
    let mut mmu = Box::new(Mmu::new());

    // If a memory read/write occurs at 0x300-0x400, then the
    // GPU should handle it.
    mmu.add_mapping(0x300, 0x400, gpu.clone());
    // If a memory read/write occurs at 0x100-0x200, then the
    // GPU should handle it.
    mmu.add_mapping(0x100, 0x200, apu.clone());
    // Otherwise the MMU will handle it.

    let mut c = Cpu {
        apu: apu,
        gpu: gpu,
        mmu: mmu,
    };

    c.mmu.read(0);
    c.mmu.write(0, 5);

    c.mmu.read(0x150);
    c.mmu.write(0x150, 5);

    c.mmu.read(0x350);
    c.mmu.write(0x350, 5);
}
```

[Rust play URL](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cca7cfeda8d590b229bd99430b78b560&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

I notice that my solution isn't ideal because the `apu` and `gpu` stored in the `Cpu` are references to `MMU`, and not to the original `Apu` or `Gpu` struct. It would need to be changed so that `Cpu` can call other functions on `Gpu` or `Apu` that aren't defined in the `MMU` trait.

Comment: Do you need threads? If not, switch to `Rc` and `Cell` / `RefCell`.

Comment: Right now I don't need threads, but not sure if I would use them in the future.

Comment: @zx64: Might want to start without then, rustc will emit an error if you try to share something you should not when moving to a threaded program anyway :)

Comment: `Mmu` trait is good idea, but why do you keep stuff as `Mutex<Box<MMU>>`, if you could just have `Mutex<Gpu>` and `Mutex<Apu>`? You're unnecessary loosing the concrete type which should be avoided. You can still call trait methods implemented by concrete type.

Also, `Arc` and `Mutex` are unncessary until you figure out which parts exacty do you want to make multirehtreaded. You probably want just `Vec<Gpu>`, or `Vec<Rc<RefCell<Gpu>>>`.
Other than this, it's not really a Rust question, that can just answered correctly.